# Как дополнить ESlint поддержкой ES9?

Tags: eslint

В качестве IDE используется **PhpStorm**.

Используемые пакеты:

- `"eslint": "^7.11.0"`
- `"eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0"`
- `"eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2"`
- `"eslint-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.0-beta.6"`

`.eslintrc`:

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2020": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "plugin:vue/recommended",
    "plugin:vue/strongly-recommended"
    //    "google"
  ],
//  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 11,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "vue",
    "vuetify"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "vuetify/grid-unknown-attributes": "error",
    "vuetify/no-legacy-grid": "error",
    "vuetify/no-deprecated-classes": "error",
    "vue/prop-name-casing": [
      "error",
      "snake_case"
    ],
    "vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline": [
      "error",
      {
        "ignoreWhenNoAttributes": true,
        "ignoreWhenEmpty": true,
        "ignores": [
          "pre",
          "textarea"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "vue/attributes-order": [
      "warn",
      {
        "order": [
          "DEFINITION",
          "LIST_RENDERING",
          "CONDITIONALS",
          "RENDER_MODIFIERS",
          "GLOBAL",
          "UNIQUE",
          "TWO_WAY_BINDING",
          "OTHER_DIRECTIVES",
          "OTHER_ATTR",
          "EVENTS",
          "CONTENT"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "vue/no-v-html": "off",
    "vue/order-in-components": [
      "warn",
      {
        "order": [
          "el",
          "name",
          "parent",
          "functional",
          [
            "delimiters",
            "comments"
          ],
          [
            "components",
            "directives",
            "filters"
          ],
          "extends",
          "mixins",
          "inheritAttrs",
          "model",
          [
            "props",
            "propsData"
          ],
          "data",
          "computed",
          "watch",
          "LIFECYCLE_HOOKS",
          "methods",
          [
            "template",
            "render"
          ],
          "renderError"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "camelcase": "off",
    "arrow-parens": [
      "error",
      "as-needed"
    ],
    "linebreak-style": [
      "error",
      "unix"
    ],
    "require-jsdoc": "error",
    "comma-dangle": [
      "error",
      "always-multiline"
    ]
  }
}
```

Необходимо настроить понимание приватных свойств **ESLint**.

Как затащить или настроить интерпретацию синтаксиса **ES9**? Решается ли проблема какими-то плагинами?

> UPD Проблема в том, что парсер `babel-eslint` не понимает ES9.

*Если кто пробовал, поделитесь опытом.*

Comment: затащил? https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: @nörbörnën нет. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Заработало. Обновил линт.

Comment: хорошо_________

Comment: @nörbörnën Линт и так понимал синтаксис. Но не может это парсить.